# Prove that $13 | (a^2 + b^3) \Rightarrow 13|b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to prove that $13|(a^2+b^3)\Rightarrow 13|b$.

I know that:

$13|a \land 13|b \Rightarrow 13|(a+b), $

$13|a \Rightarrow 13| a^2,$

$13|b \Rightarrow 13| b^3,$

$13|a \land 13|b \Rightarrow 13|(a^2 +b^3).$

But I don't know how to build a proof with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not true: take $a=1$ and $b=4$.